# How would you tell Django to return ImageField.url (not relative path) when serializing a model?

Tags: django, serialization, django-models

ImageField on the model

```
some_image = models.ImageField(upload_to= get_upload_path)
```

This is what i use for serializing:

```
data = serializers.serialize("json",ModelName.objects.all(),use_natural_keys=True)
```

the json i get for some_image is relative to the MEDIA_URL

to solve it manualy i call some_image.url, and that works fine, how do i make it so this will be the default value that the image returns when using `serializers.serialize`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs for specifying which fields get serialized: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields

It sounds like you should include url and all the other fields except some_image.

Comment: i use that option now to exclude some_image and add it manually after calling it's 'url' key. that works. but what i need is for it to return it's url by default, something like natural_key on a model, am i clear?

Comment: You might be asking for too much magic here. I guess your next move is to subclass ImageField and make it return the url instead of the relative url to media.

Comment: i admit i'm new to Django, just wanted to know i'm doing things right, so when you implement an API call, i.e just to send back a json of a model you manually serialize file urls, that's fine. thanks!

Comment: Don't give up hope just yet -- There might be a great way to do what you want; I just don't know what it is. I would prefer the way you are already solving it -- it keeps the model clean and makes it obvious where the url is coming from when you or someone else goes back to look at the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a proper solution too. But eventually came up with following code:

```
stores = list(Store.objects.all().values('title', 'logo'))
for store in stores:
    store['logo'] = \
          request.build_absolute_uri(settings.MEDIA_URL+store['logo'])
stores_json = json.dumps(stores)
```

Comment: You should pass the request context to the serializer so it can build an absolute path for the images for you.